# MySQL query inside query while loop not working (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

BIG EDIT: I've trimmed the code as much as possible while getting the same notice.
So I'm trying to use the variable `$tour` which is defined in the first `if(isset...`. This if creates a second submit that when pressed should print the value `$tour` but I get the following output:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: torneo in /home/user/public_html/edit/file.php on line 19
1
before loop

Notice: Undefined variable: torneo in /home/user/public_html/edit/file.php on line 21
```

The trimmed code is:

```
<form method="POST">
TORNEO: <select name="torneo">
            <option value="DSHN ADULTO">DSHN ADULTO</option>
            <option value="NFL">NFL</option>
        </select>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="ELEGIR" name="input1"/>
<br />
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
if(isset($_POST['input1'])){
    $torneo = $_POST['torneo'];
    echo $torneo;
    echo "<br><input type='submit' name='input2' value='CREAR'/>";
}     
if(isset($_POST['input2'])){
    echo $torneo."1";
    echo "<br>before loop<br>";
    while ($torneo){
        echo "Updated! ".$torneo."<br>";        
    }
}  
?>
</form>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you connecting with mysqli?Also in your query shouldn't  be `WHERE WEEK(DATE)=.... AND YEAR(DATE)=..`?

Comment: @Mihai Yes I am. Ive been cpnnecting with the same script for a long time and never got any issue though.

Comment: Check to see if your query actually returned some rows.  Run the query directly on the database (ie, command line, MySql Workbench).  Print out $query to be sure it's the proper format.

Comment: $myrow['palce'] -- looks like a spelling misteak.

Comment: @dar7yl I know that the query works beacause I use it twice in this same script (the first one is exactly the same). That one doe the work fine. Indeed was a spelling mistake, thanks!

Comment: The vast majority of code in this question is clearly not relevant to the problem. Can you narrow it down a bit please.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Edited the question with the relevant part. Tried to narrow it as much as I could. Ill try to make a different approach though, any ideas? thanks!

Comment: Try adding this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575482/how-do-i-enable-error-reporting-in-php and see what it tells you, then.

Comment: @rm-vanda Thank you very much! Very useful script that is! I get 3 errors that say that $week, $tour and $year are not defined. Wierd though because if I 'echo' them just before de 'if(isset($_POST['input2'].....' they print...

Comment: Please narrow it down more, but constructing a [testcase](http://sscce.org). You'll likely find the process of doing this reveals the problem to you.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit thank you for the advice. Now I did trim the code desently (I believe). So its not about the connection. I just cant get the variable through the second submit... Thanks!

Comment: @EnricTomás: Yes! Woohoo!! This is now a perfect testcase. :D Excellent work. Hopefully you can now see the extreme value in doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my problem is here:

[Why do I keep losing variable values when submitting a second form on the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335533/why-do-i-keep-losing-variable-values-when-submitting-a-second-form-on-the-same-p)

Thanks everyone who helped, Im really very thankful to all!

Comment: You may also benefit from switching your while() loop to a foreach() loop --

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "</form>";
mysqli_close($db);
```

...
        mysqli_close($db);

You have an extraneous close, before the second part of your script.

Comment: I see you open the database again..  Why not keep it open and close it at the end (you can test if it is opened).

Comment: I tried keeping it open from the very beginning and closing it at the end and still no loop. Tried different combinatios and the nothind :(